# Updated Anaconda, error message "cannot import name 'moduleTNC'" when importing scipy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I updated anaconda on windows using `conda update anaconda`. Now my my ipython notebook, which starts with

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
...
```

is giving me errors:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2bb1109a8767> in <module>()
      2 from numpy.random import randn
      3 import pandas as pd
----> 4 from scipy import stats
      5 import matplotlib as mpl
      6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>()
    336 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    337 
--> 338 from .stats import *
    339 from .distributions import *
    340 from .rv import *

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>()
    187 
    188 from . import futil
--> 189 from . import distributions
    190 
    191 from ._rank import rankdata, tiecorrect

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py in <module>()
      8 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
      9 
---> 10 from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
     11                                     rv_frozen)
     12 

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in <module>()
     21 
     22 # for root finding for discrete distribution ppf, and max likelihood estimation
---> 23 from scipy import optimize
     24 
     25 # for functions of continuous distributions (e.g. moments, entropy, cdf)

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py in <module>()
    174 
    175 from .optimize import *
--> 176 from ._minimize import *
    177 from ._root import *
    178 from .minpack import *

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in <module>()
     30 # constrained minimization
     31 from .lbfgsb import _minimize_lbfgsb
---> 32 from .tnc import _minimize_tnc
     33 from .cobyla import _minimize_cobyla
     34 from .slsqp import _minimize_slsqp

C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\tnc.py in <module>()
     35 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     36 
---> 37 from scipy.optimize import moduleTNC, approx_fprime
     38 from .optimize import MemoizeJac, OptimizeResult, _check_unknown_options
     39 from numpy import inf, array, zeros, asfarray

ImportError: cannot import name moduleTNC
```

If I remove the line causing the error, then I get an error importing seaborn, etc...

What have I done wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried updating `scipy` after updating `anaconda`?

Comment: I did `easy_install scipy` and got `C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-14.3-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py:2512: PEP
440Warning: 'llvmlite (0.2.2-1-gbcb15be)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may
 find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend
 to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
Searching for scipy
Best match: scipy 0.15.1
Adding scipy 0.15.1 to easy-install.pth file`. I then get the same error as before when I try to run the notebook.

Comment: Don't use `easy_install` - Use `conda update scipy`. If a specific package is not provided by `conda`, use `pip install` instead.

Comment: ok, now I get `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in c:\users\me\anaconda\lib\site-pac
kages`

Comment: Please read my comment carefully. You only get the last message when you use `pip`. Note that `conda update scipy` is the best way to update scipy in a conda environment.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. But with `conda update scipy` I get a different message. It's too long to fit here, but part of it is `InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.` The message ends with `# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Me\Anaconda:
#
scipy                     0.15.1               np19py27_0`

Comment: So either anaconda's `scipy` is borked, or you have an older version lingering around. I would try to uninstall scipy with conda, then use `pip uninstall` to see if there's still some old version around. After that you can install `scipy` with `conda` again. Beyond that I have no more ideas. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thanks a lot.

Comment: sklearn GitHub issue about it: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4830 The solution mentioned there is a same as asmeurer.

Answer (score 6):

I spotted the underlying pyd file to be named moduletnc.pyd instead of moduleTNC.pyd. When I capitalized the last three letters, the problem was solved for me.

Comment: Worked on Windows 10 with WinPython 3.5. Thanks!

Comment: solved the problem for me too. thank you @user7316501

Answer (score 5):

The following solution worked for me for windows 10
1. go to -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize
2. rename moduletnc file to moduleTNC

Comment: Worked for me too on Windows 10 with WinPython 3.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try `conda install -f scipy`. That will force conda to reinstall scipy.

Comment: Per: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6188  This also worked 
`conda remove scipy scikit-learn -y; conda install scipy scikit-learn -y`